# ALSA aplay mono file but returns channel count non available

Tags: alsa, sox

I have a `test.wav` file that I wanna play through speaker using ALSA. I also have sox installed on the system. All sound cards are installed properly. `aplay -L` and `arecord -L` return the correct value.

However I wasn't able to play this `test.wav`.

```
aplay -c1 -r 48000 -f S16_LE test.wav
$ Playing WAVE 'test.wav': Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
  aplay: set_params:1345: Channels count non available
```

But when i used sox, the system had no problem and it shows that the file is indeed 1 channel at 16-bit

```
$ Encoding: Signed PCM
  Channels: 1 @ 16-bit
  Samplerate: 48000Hz
```

I really have no clue what the reason could be. Any help is appreciated! Thank you guys in advance!

EDIT:

1. My mistake when I hand typed the message printed in the terminal, it is indeed 1@16 bit when I used SoX instead.
2. `.asoundrc`

```
pcm.!default {
 type hw
 card 0
}
ctl.!default {
 type hw
 card 0
}
```

3. When I use `arecord`, I need to specify the channel counts:
   `arecord -c 2 -r 48000 -f S16_LE test.wav`
   Otherwise it will return the same error above.
   But then I have no problem playing `test.wav` if it is recorded using `arecord`. It is weird that I can't play a `test.wav` if it is imported from elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm, `Channels: 2@16-bit` seems like stereo to me. But: Can you try to play as root? maybe you don't have the rights to change the card-config.

Comment: You do not need -c/r/f options for .wav files. I guess sox automatically converts the samples. Did you do any changes to your .asoundrc or asound.conf?

Comment: @CL. I did changed `.asoundrc` in order to make my external sound card default. I am using a HiFiberry dac. I will put the file content in the edits

Comment: @stoney You are correct! It is sudo!! Thank you so much!! Do you know how to change the settings so that my current user `pi` can also use arecord? I will accept your answer if you don't mind answering below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing the configuration of the user `pi` to use `hw` devices, you have disabled all automatic sample format conversions.

To set only the card number, use:

```
defaults.pcm.card 0
defaults.ctl.card 0
```

To change this for all users instead, put this into `/etc/asound.conf`.

Comment: That is something new i learn today. Sorry, just to clarify, `/etc/asound.conf` applies to all users, and I'd put the content of `.asoundrc` in `asound.conf` instead correct?

Comment: And where would I set up `defaults.pcm.card`?

Comment: This goes into the same file (the user's `.asoundrc` or the global `/etc/asound.conf`).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my sudo permission problem by doing the following:

`sudo nano /root/.asoundrc`

```
pcm.!default {
 type hw
 card 0
}
ctl.!default {
 type hw
 card 0
}
```

And then I commented out `.asoundrc` in home directory and `asound.conf`. Now I can use `aplay` and `arecord` on wav files without specifying the options.

The solution is from [alsa-project web sit](https://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc).